# Generate wrong "Update" query cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to update data using below code but it is generating wrong SQL query. don't understand why it is generating wrong one. Please help me out.

```
$data = array();
$data['Pers']['etat'] = 1;
$data['Pers']['Activation'] = '';

$this->Pers->id = $results['Pers']['persID'];               
$this->Pers->save($data);   

Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'bdr+.pers.persID' in 
 'where     clause'
 SQL Query: UPDATE `bdr+`.`pers` SET `etat` = 1, `Activation` = '', 
 `date_time` = '2014-03-19   11:33:21' WHERE `bdr+.pers.persID` = 37
```

It means `bdr+.pers.persID` is generating wrong. Don't understand why it is generating like this.

Comment: please post your Pers Model file

Answer (score 0):

Your code containing `` bdr+.pers.persID` = '37' `` because  `$results['Pers']['persID']` supplying 37

Answer (score 0):

check if this `$results['Pers']['persID']` variable if it is returning a proper format

then try this

```
$data = array();
$data['Pers']['persID'] = $results['Pers']['persID'];
$data['Pers']['etat'] = 1;
$data['Pers']['Activation'] = '';    
//Just to make sure your model is loaded
$this->loadModel('Pers');
if ($this->Pers->save($data, false)) {   
    echo 'Pres has been saved :) ';   
}
```

Comment: check your table name in model. sound your table name is incorrect. the error is: 'bdr+.pers.persID' column not exists. your column name should be pers.persID Not 'bdr+.pers.persID'

Comment: Actually, It is generating wrong sql query. My table name in model is public $useTable   = 'pers';

Comment: what is your model name of then?

Comment: My Model name is "Pers"